# How to get the latest version of .net CF application?

Tags: c#, compact-framework

How to get the latest version of my .net CF application ? Why `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString()` always returns `1.0.0.0`?

Should I set application version manually?

Comment: Yes, you need to set the application version yourself. There are however, add-ons for VS that automatically increment the version on every build. [This is my favorite](http://autobuildversion.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The Application version number is inside your `AssemblyInfo.cs` file, located in the properties folder of your solution in Visual Studio.

You can set the value with a star, like `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.*")]` and this number will change at every build.